# Dummy variables are missing when I ran a panel regression. How to display the dummy variables?

Tags: r, plm

I am trying to do a panel data regression with fixed effect estimator. The sample data can be seen below:

```r
structure(list(DOILN = c(4.3207, 4.1675, 4.0718, 3.8239, 3.6247, 
2.044, 1.3759, 1.4596, 1.486, 4.3136), ROSLN = c(-2.0178, -2.2647, 
-4.0632, -3.9933, -3.441, -3.6077, -2.8291, -2.6271, -2.4051, 
-1.7239), IRATE = c(-0.0295, -0.1228, 0.00288, 0.03388, -0.0295, 
0.00288, 0.03849, 0.03388, 0.07165, 0.04809), GDPGROW = c(0.11731, 
0.07891, 0.05072, 0.05745, 0.11731, 0.05072, 0.02142, 0.05745, 
0.06645, -0.01765), ISOCode = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("BRA", "CHN", "IND", "RUS"), class = "factor"), 
    ISOCodeBRA = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ISOCodeRUS = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), ISOCodeIND = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1), ISOCodeCHN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), .Names = c("DOILN", "ROSLN", "IRATE", "GDPGROW", "ISOCode", 
"ISOCodeBRA", "ISOCodeRUS", "ISOCodeIND", "ISOCodeCHN"), row.names = c("120453-2010", 
"120453-2011", "120453-2012", "120453-2014", "133431-2010", "133431-2012", 
"133431-2013", "133431-2014", "133431-2015", "200448-2009"), class = c("pdata.frame", 
"data.frame"), index = structure(list(GCKey = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("120453", "133431", 
"200448"), class = "factor"), FiscalY = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("GCKey", 
"FiscalY"), row.names = c(915L, 647L, 35L, 41L, 83L, 68L, 220L, 
330L, 497L, 1219L), class = c("pindex", "data.frame")))
```

However, when I introduced dummy variables for the countries (ISOCode), they are missing from the summary. Also, I still got N dummy variables, instead of N-1.

I used model.matrix to create dummy variables. First I did this to create the dummy variable and include it to my dataframe

```r
dBRICna <-cbind(dBRICna, model.matrix(~ -1+ISOCode, data = dBRICna))
```

then I create a panel dataframe based on my initial dataframe. The panel regression is as follows:

```r
fix.cdum <-Plm(ROSLN~DOILN+GDPGROW+IRATE+ISOCodeBRA+ISOCodeRUS+ISOCodeIND+ISOCodeCHN, 
data = pbric,model = "within")
```

The resulting regression is as follow:

```r
Oneway (individual) effect Within Model

Call:
plm(formula = ROSLN ~ DOILN + IRATE + GDPGROW + ISOCodeBRA + 
    ISOCodeCHN + ISOCodeIND + ISOCodeRUS, data = pbric, model = "within")

Unbalanced Panel: n = 308, T = 1-7, N = 1574

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-6.4169648 -0.1066602  0.0075008  0.1344821  2.7955477 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t-value Pr(>|t|)  
DOILN    0.031935   0.055124  0.5793  0.56247  
IRATE   -1.194691   0.486961 -2.4534  0.01429 *
GDPGROW -0.041300   0.767433 -0.0538  0.95709  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    240.19
Residual Sum of Squares: 238.52
R-Squared:      0.006922
Adj. R-Squared: -0.23683
F-statistic: 2.93449 on 3 and 1263 DF, p-value: 0.032416
```

As observed, the dummy variables are not shown on the regression result. Would be really thankful if anyone can advise me on this matter!

Comment: Please cut down your data to a sufficiently small size that it can be shown in the question but sufficiently large that it still illustrates the problem.  Do this by showing the output of `dput(X)` where `X` is your cut down input data frame.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advise against producing the dummy variables yourself. Let R do it for you during the model estimation by using a factor for the variable from which you want the dummy variables to be derived: just use `factor(ISOCode)` in the formula. The manual way is error prone.

Then, use `model.matrix` after the model estimation to look at the data after the within transformation inherent to the fixed effects model:

```
mod <-plm(ROSLN ~ DOILN + GDPGROW + IRATE + factor(ISOCode), 
                         data = dat, model = "within")
model.matrix(mod)

    DOILN    GDPGROW     IRATE factor(ISOCode)RUS
   0.224725  0.0412125 -0.000615                  0
   0.071525  0.0028125 -0.093915                  0
  -0.024175 -0.0253775  0.031765                  0
  -0.272075 -0.0186475  0.062765                  0
   1.626660  0.0546400 -0.052980                  0
   0.045960 -0.0119500 -0.020600                  0
  -0.622140 -0.0412500  0.015010                  0
  -0.538440 -0.0052200  0.010400                  0
  -0.512040  0.0037800  0.048170                  0
   0.000000  0.0000000  0.000000                  0
```

Two issues become apparent: One row is all zeros as there was only one observation for the individual. This row will be dropped in the model estimation. The column for the ISO codes is all zeros and will be dropped as well.

This is why the model summary looks like it looks.